# Can I list all my scripts without any other types of documents in Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script

`Google Apps Scripts` was integrated into `Google Drive` last year.

Can anyone tell me how I can list all my `scripts` in `Google Drive`
without any other types of documents such as `spreadsheets` or `text` files.

I can filter spreadsheets by this [URL](https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#query/vr?view=2&filter=spreadsheets).

A [help page](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375114) for Google Drive

says filter works only for `document`, `spreadsheet`, `presentation`, `drawing`, 
`image`, `video`, `image_or_video`, `pdf`, and `textdoc`.

I am looking for a way like `"filter=scripts"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above answer doesn't work with the new Google Drive search (at least for me).

Searching for [`type:script`](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/search?q=type:script) does work (but doesn't show Spreadsheet-bound scripts).

Answer (score 11):

You can indicate the file type in the Google Drive search bar, [`type:application/vnd.google-apps.script`](https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#search/type:application/vnd.google-apps.script).

[image: Search Bar]

Comment: This operator doesn't seem to work on the latest Google Drive web interface.

Comment: it works for me and gives the same results as for /search?q=type:script