# Listing all container-bound scripts in all my documents and spreadsheets

Tags: list, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

How can I list all scripts bound in my documents and spreadsheets?
Query string "type:application/vnd.google-apps.script owner:me" shows only independent scripts.
(It is my old question [Can I list all my scripts without any other types of documents in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803202/can-i-list-all-my-scripts-without-any-other-types-of-documents-in-google-drive))

Sometimes I need to reuse scripts in certainly existing spreadsheet
but I don't get the name of the container.
Should I open all spreadsheets one by one?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way you can do that in the search box :-( I have the same problem and I'm opening file by file so far... You always can [create a library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#testAndDebug), but for a *hackish* script makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. File, Document or Spreadsheet do not provide any information about scripts which is included in those containers. Hmmm. I open containers one by one for now.

Comment: Filed on google-apps-script-issues as Issue 4125 (Enhancement). https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4215

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, and it's from a comment to the issue that your  *Issue 4125 (Enhancement)* was merged to:

[Issue 4096: Means to manage and search over standalone and container-bound scripts](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4096)

> In the meantime, note that any script that you've authorized should have an entry in https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions for that account, so you should be able to find active scripts there.

Over there I was able to find some other scripts not listed in the following Google Drive search:

[type:application/vnd.google-apps.script](https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=type:application/vnd.google-apps.script)

(but not all)

Comment: THX for useful info.